# VueJS : global variables not reconized in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently upgrading my front-end to a gulp-based application.

I have an issue with Vue.js, in fact, I have these two errors :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "params" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'websiteUrl' of undefined"

My code worked perfectly before, So I don't understand where my mistake is :/

This is my html code :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  /** Params **/
  let params = {};
  let userData = {};

  params.websiteUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com/';
  params.websiteMediasUrl = 'http://medias.mywebsite.com/';
  params.websiteStatsUrl = 'http://stats.mywebsite.com/';

  userData.isLogged = 01;
  userData.isAdmin = 01;
  userData.canVote = 01;
</script>

<!-- FOSRoutingBundle -->
<script src="/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>

<!-- Application -->
<script src="/build/js/vendor/bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script> <!-- VueJs is here -->
<script src="/build/js/app/app.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- Search bar -->
<script type="application/javascript">
    Vue.component('media-info', {
        delimiters: ["<%", "%>"],
        props: {
            elt: {}
        },
        template: `<div class="media-box"><% params.websiteUrl %></div>`
    });
```

And somewhere in my HTML file, I call

Do you have any idea ? :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the params variable to the Vue component's data.

```
    Vue.component('media-info', {
    delimiters: ["<%", "%>"],
    data() {
        return {
           params,
        };
    },
    props: {
        elt: {}
    },
    template: `<div class="media-box"><% params.websiteUrl %></div>`
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but I don't understand why it was working before :/